# I fail to bake color using "window" option in Texture coordinate node

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking

Please look at this example. I made a simple node tree and i want to bake what i see in viewport. I want to use "window" option in Texture Coordinates node specifically.
But when i try to Bake it into image, texture goes wrong from i see in viewport.
I didn't find any info about this issue, mb it isn't possible idk....[image: what i want to image texture be like after bake:]

[image: what i get]

Comment: Try with a camera. It makes sense, that window is not a very well defined thing in context of baking, because there can be many 3d Viewport windows open. There can only be one active camera at a time in a scene, so I think camera has a way greater chance of working.

Answer (score 1):

@MartynasŽiemys's comment is correct ... To bake texture coordinates type **Window** you need a **Camera** object in your scene. Even you can see texture coordinates are used for 3D viewport, Bake operator uses only what Camera object see.

Default camera view ...
[image]

Bake **without** Camera object in a Scene ...
[image]

Bake **with** Camera object in a Scene ...
[image]

Comment: its all good but "Camera" and "Window" options in Texture coordinates are nor the same at all.

Comment: Sorry for confusion ... I mean Camera object (not Camera Texture Coordinates) ... I edited description to make it clear :)